# Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-5.0' Linux ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c#, linux, .net

Как можно исправить эту ошибку ? (полагаю, что .NET  5.0 больше не поддерживается )

```
root@myIp:/# sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0 dotnet-runtime-5.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-5.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-5.0'
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-runtime-5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-runtime-5.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-runtime-5.0'
```

Comment: да, поставить .NET 6 или 7, они должны быть доступны на ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Вот тут можно скачать и поставить нужный рантайм и sdk https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/core/master/release-notes/releases-index.json - вот тут написано, что 5.0 закончила свой жизненный путь. Так что ставь 7.0.